# How to specific Scala style rules for a specific file/directory?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalastyle

I have some cucumber stepDef steps which are more than more than 120 characters in length, I want to exclude all stepDef files from Scala style warning.

Is there a way to to exclude a specific files/directories, using xml tag only for `FileLineLengthChecker` condition?

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping the entire file in the following [comment filter](http://www.scalastyle.org/configuration.html#comment-filters) in effect excludes the file from `FileLineLengthChecker` rule:

```
// scalastyle:off line.size.limit
val foobar = 134
// scalastyle:on line.size.limit
```

`line.size.limit` is the ID of [`FileLineLengthChecker`](http://www.scalastyle.org/rules-1.0.0.html#org_scalastyle_file_FileLineLengthChecker) rule.

Multiple rules can be switched off simultaneously like so

```
// scalastyle:off line.size.limit
// scalastyle:off line.contains.tab
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. Is there a delimiter for combining multiple rules ?

Comment: Multiple rules can be combined by listing them one after another as shown in the edited answer. The following test is useful to deduce comment filter syntax: https://github.com/scalastyle/scalastyle/blob/5c4bb3e1d6b7666c4546bbbd10c4d503455bbc9e/src/test/scala/org/scalastyle/CommentFilterTest.scala

Answer (score 0):

**scalastyle must Paired use**

*// scalastyle:off line.size.limit*

```
_FUNC_(str, regexp) - Searches a string for a regular expression and returns an integer that indicates the beginning position of the matched substring. Positions are 1-based, not 0-based. If no match is found, returns 0.
```

*// scalastyle:on line.size.limit*